# Windows password crypt support

Tags: winapi, password-encryption

I looking for a Windows replacement for Unix crypt(3), is there any native windows function equivalent to the Unix crypt function?

Comment: Why? It's one of the weakest pieces of cryptography ever published. Please be secure and use something stronger.

Comment: I mostly want to use it for backwards compatibility. Do you know of a good replacement that is native supported in Windows?

Comment: Please define "equivalent to the Unix crypt function"

Comment: I want to have a password files, what are the alternatives to use crypt, is there something directly supported by Windows API.

Comment: NIST recommends PBKDF2 for a password verifier, of course Windows has a different name for it: [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx). Specify an iteration count such that a call takes about 100ms of CPU time.

Comment: I end up using BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2 https://github.com/zeroc-ice/ice/blob/master/cpp/src/Glacier2CryptPermissionsVerifier/CryptPermissionsVerifierI.cpp#L470

Answer (score -1):

You want the Windows [Crypto API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx).  There's a pretty straightforward [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382019(v=vs.85).aspx) available.  If you're using C#, there are easier to use wrappers in the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.